# Display Product from one website on reseller website

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, feed

I am doing some work on a WordPress website for a client that is reselling products from another website. Originally I was going to just recreate them on the client's website but I then realized that there would be a lot of issues in ensuring that the content for each product is always up-to-date.

So what I'm looking for is some way of being able to get a list of products from one website which then on the client's website, I can then perform a query on the list to get the right product that I need to display for each page. This should also then ensure that if any changes are made to any products, that the information displayed on the website that is reselling these products is always correct and up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask the other website's operators for it. They might have an API or an RSS feed containing the product information.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question Martijn. I looked at RSS Feeds (they don't have an API) but what I wasn't clear about is whether it's possible to get a specific post from a feed. So I know it is easy to get the full list of products in an RSS Feed but I then wanted to get a specific post from the feed so that I can display a specific product on each of my product pages.

Comment: There is no generic standard for 'querying' RSS feeds, but the site you are using may have their own standard for this or provide a special RSS feed containing all products.